# Prayers and how many times a day

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Are you meant to pray 5 or 6 times a day? I have looked up prayer times where it gives 6 times for prayer as they have put two separate times for fajr and Soboh

Comment: Are you sure the different time is labelled for "Soboh"? I often see timetables list a separate time for *shuruq* (which is sunrise, i.e. the *end* of the *fajr* time), but never seen one list a separate time for *subh*.

Comment: Well there's fajr = the time and fajr the prayer some madhabs distinguish between the fard/farz prayer calling it clearly sobh (other say the fard prayer of fajr) and the sunna prayer which should be done before calling it "fajr". As the Time to pray sobh or fajr fard is between the fajr time and the shuruq (=sunrise). So there are only 5 fard/farz prayers a day! But 6 Times to distinguish when one should perform them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we have 5 fard prayers, because fajr and subuh are the same prayer but with different names. **Evidence:**

> narrated by Muslim (656) from ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn Abi ‘Amrah who said: ‘Uthmaan ibn ‘Affaan entered the mosque after Maghrib prayer and sat by himself. I sat beside him and he said: O son of my brother, I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “Whoever prays ‘Isha’ in congregation, it is as if he spent half the night in prayer, and whoever prays **Subh** in congregation, it is as if he spent the entire night in prayer.”
>
> And al-Bukhaari (555) and Muslim (632) narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Angels come to you in succession by night and by day, and they meet at **Fajr** prayer and at ‘Asr prayer, then those who stayed among you ascend and He (Allaah) asks them, although He knows best, ‘How did you leave My slaves?’ They say: ‘We left them when they were praying and we came to them when they were praying."

As you can notice, in the first hadeeth, the term "Subh" was mentioned as the fard, and in the second hadeeth, the term "Fajr" was also mentioned as the fard. *So, we can conclude that Fajr and Subh are the same one prayer but with different terms.*

After Fajr/Subh, we have Duhr, Asr, Maghrib  and Ishaa' to give a total of five prayers.

Comment: Oh I see thank you very much for your time and references! It was much appreciated and has clarified a lot for me.

Comment: You can mark this answer "accept" if you think it fully answers your question. @user14134